# Using "php://memory" for I/O - can't read back value written

Tags: php, io

So given this simple example:

```
<?php
$memory = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');

fwrite($memory, 'asdf', 4);

$value = fread($memory, 3);

var_dump($value);
```

I was expecting `$value` to contain the string `"asd"` but instead I get an empty string. Is there anything obvious about this example that needs to change? Is my expectation incorrect? If `$value` should indeed contain `"asd"` what might cause this to happen (a configuration/php.ini issue perhaps)?

Comment: Seek back to the beginning first. The same "offset" is used for reading and writing and advanced with both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the internal pointer of the stream is at index 4 after you write the data, you need to [`fseek`](http://php.net/fseek) back to the beginning of your stream:

```
// fwrite
fseek($memory, 0);  // same as rewind($memory);
// fread
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this would also work (and is basically the equivalent to `fseek($memory, 0);`):

```
rewind($memory);
```